# Add JSON file to Swift Playgrounds

Tags: json, swift, ipad-playgrounds

I've created a playground book on swift playgrounds, but I don't know how to add a JSON file to the directory. *Can* you add JSON files to swift playgrounds (ipad)? If so, how?

Comment: You can add files to the resources folder of your playground.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the '+' icon on the top right corner of the swift `Playgrounds` and choose the json file  by clicking `Insert from...` option. Then use the below code to read the data from `json` file.

```
import Foundation

do {
    guard let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "json") else { fatalError() }
    let text = try String(contentsOf: fileUrl, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(text)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```